# 401 error python MongoDB connection

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to set a connection between Python and MongoDB to store tweets. My problem is that I get 401 in each request with `Mylistener`. Could you please help to fix this ?

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):
        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.tweet_data = []
     def on_data(self, data):
        while (time.time() - self.time)<self.limit:
              try:
                client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
                client.server_info()
                db = client.tweets_db
                collection = db.collect_tweets
                tweet = json.loads(data)
                collect_tweets.insert(tweet)
                return True
            except BaseException as e:
                print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
            return True
      def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
Keywords_list=['word1','word2','word3']
twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener(start_time, time_limit))
```

Comment: 401 means the url is password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to authenticate with the database right after creating the new MongoClient instance:

```
client.tweets_db.authenticate('user', 'password')
```

See [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html) for more detailed examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually the problem was with twitter API not with mongodb connection, I had to reset the system clock and it worked just fine.